# Playing sound loops through winsound python

Tags: python-3.x, winsound

I am trying to play background music through winsound, but even though I put in

```
winsound.SND_LOOP
```

It still wasn't looping, just playing once. My code is as follows

```
import winsound
import os
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Travis\\Downloads')
winsound.PlaySound('SS.wav',winsound.SND_LOOP)
```

Comment: I have answered your question

Answer (score 4):

You need to use:

`winsound.PlaySound('C:/Windows/Media/notify.wav', winsound.SND_LOOP + winsound.SND_ASYNC)`

This will loop the sound until the program closes.

Comment: I can't play the sound without SND_FILENAME. After putting SND_ASYNC in, my program terminate right away.